# Default SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

I have a converter which converts a custom object to a `SolidColorBrush` for ListView text color of items that can be either from the color Red or Black.
The problem is that the PointerOver template (and the others) for the listview automatically inverts text colors to match the contrast, but the colors that the converter is setting are not changing automaticaly, so my question is is there a default SolidColorBrush which will not make this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `default(SolidColorBrush)` is `null`.

You could use [ItemContainerStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx) instead of or together with the converter to use different item styles, including brushes. Your current solution is likely overriding `{TemplateBinding Foreground}` set somewhere in one of the default templates which breaks the chain of dependency property value inference. You can check this for more info on dependency property [Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: for null I dont get any color. I have figured out that if I set the color explicitly that the color set in ListViewItem style doesnt change thet color, so that this style is applied before the converter sets this color and I need it the other way

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SolidColorBrush defaultBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
controlObject.BorderBrush = defaultBrush;
```